# Arm mount for GPS Watch

Tags: running

I am a moderately fast runner and really do not want to add 55+ grams to my wrist. Arm is OK. Anyone have experience mounting the GPS watch on the arm - a la' iPod armband?

Comment: On this forum I have the opportunity to be reminded how low rep users often get treated. Downvoted without explanation on apparently reasonable questions. I do strive to treat low rep users better than that.

Comment: I understand, but after [these instances](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/656/what-is-wrong-with-this-question-http-sports-stackexchange-com-questions-139#comment1425_656) of explaining a downvote, I completely understand why users tend not to explain downvotes.

Comment: Everyone will run into occasional instances that are not smooth. Personally I downvote carefully and usually provide feedback. Even more often I just do the latter and do not downvote.   To each their own.   Sometimes the downvote is clearly warranted - e.g. I used different search terms and there existed applicable answers.  But w/o feedback who knows.   It is difficult to get started for newcomers.

Comment: That's spot on.

Comment: This question currently has zero downvotes, so it's not clear what your complaint is. Moreover, three people currently vote to close, two because this is off-topic (it's not about sports as defined by meta). As someone who seems experienced with SE sites, you should be much more aware of how different SE sites will view questions w.r.t. what is "reasonable" than an arbitrary low-rep user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into one of the fitness tracking wearables, like the FitBit (which is a very light wrist device) or some of the GPS tags, which can be the size of a key fob.

Comment: Cheers - I was just browsing unanswered questions and saw yours. I recently bought my wife a fitbit so thought I'd pop this up for you as an option. I know it doesn't really answer how to mount your existing watch, so I understand the downvote.

Comment: No it's even better: it answers the *need* - as opposed to a literal answer to the OP.